# Android Studio JNI support

Tags: android-studio, android-ide

I would like to switch to Android Studio but it still do not support JNI projects. In my project Android.mk file is quite complex. I am doing many things in native code (FFMPEG and other c-implementations). Is it planned to extend Eclipse to Android Studio project converter to deal with converting of JNI part?? And more or less when it will be available??

Comment: you can continue to use eclipse to develop your native code and build android project with android studio and .so dependencies.

Comment: i do not think it is good idea to use 2 IDE to develop application. Maintaining source code in two IDE synchronising it etc.

Comment: You can use module structure for your app so it would have android and native modules independent from each other. Android Studio is java IDE. It is just recently JetBrains (the developers behind IntelliJ IDE which was extended by Google tools team to build AndroidStudio on their code) released CLion C++ IDE. So I imagine it would be possible to build native applications at the same IDE someday. But we are not there yet.

Comment: Yes but when developing native part I am working on Android part as well in parallel... I am looking for information about future plans of Android Studio development and cannot see it. I received e-mail from JetBrains that Stackoverflow is correct place for asking question about Android Studio Development.

Comment: You can check official roadmap here: http://tools.android.com/roadmap. NDK is certainly on android tools team radar. I think they will make an announcement at the GoogleIO next month if NDK integration will be done anytime soon. IMHO, you better to start looking for Eclipse enhancement tools, like https://github.com/eclipse/andmore/releases/tag/0.5-M1

Comment: I will wait for GoogleIO. Anyway it is really strange that Android Studio is now 1.0 and do not have basic functionllity.

Comment: It seems 1.3 includes JNI support http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/android-ndk-preview